# html with embedded css file not filling up Body

Tags: html, css, formatting

I am trying to create the following resume using html/css, and the actual resume is not filling up the body of the html.

[resume 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XVuE.jpg)

[resume2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbZQd.jpg)

The CSS code for the resume is as follows.

```
  <style>
  body {
    background-color: white;
    width: 612px;
    height: 792px;

}
h1  {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
font-size: 70px;


}
html, body {
overflow: auto;
}

h1:after {

content:' ';
display:block;
border:3px solid black;
margin-bottom: 0px;

}
p{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30px;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 15px;
margin-top: 15px;

}
dt {
display: list-item;
list-style-type: disc;
list-style-position: inside;
}
dl {
margin-top: 15px;
}
h3 {
text-align: left;
font-size: 19px;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}


</style>
```

I was wondering if there is any CSS line that can fix this issue

Comment: Please include your HTML as well to form a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the reason:

```
body {
    width: 612px;
    height: 792px;
}
```

You're forcing the whole body of your website to be set at 612x792 pixels, so of course it won't fill up the entire view